# Click off input field event in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mouseclick-event

Suppose you have an input field in an Angular JS app

```
 <input id="title" type="text" name="title" placeholder="enter a title" ng-model="item.title" />
```

I would like to display some feedback to the user about the validity of the input data AFTER the user has completed interacting with the input but I cannot think of a directive to watch the "click off" event. That is, when a user types into the form, then either tabs next or clicks anywhere else.

How do I capture the "click off and element" event.

Please note, this is in contrast to an "off-click" event, where the event refers to when a user clicks anywhere BUT a given element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ng-blur` directive.

**ng-blur:**

> Specify custom behavior on blur event.
>
> A blur event fires when an element has lost focus.

**Note:** *the print you see in the `ng-blur` is nothing but `console.log` using this for convenience, refer my fiddle!*

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**JS:**

```
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <input id="title" type="text" name="title" placeholder="enter a title" ng-model="item.title" ng-blur="print('lost focus')" />
</div>
```

**References:**

1. [ng-blur](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Naren's answer, ngBlur is the directive you are looking for.

However, since you're trying to implement validation, you should know that angular has built-in validation functionality that will handle the events for you and using them is a better practice than reinventing the validation 'wheel'.

Use validation directives like ngRequired, ngMinlength, ngMaxlength and ngPattern for simple validation needs.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Use Angular UI's uiValidate directive for custom validation including validation through asynchronous http requests.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-validate

Comment: yes, I am using angular's validation directives as well. thank you. but I dont believe there is an analogue to ng-blur, is there?

Comment: Angular validation directives by default trigger on input or blur. If you want just blur, you can specify so in ngModelOptions.